# Resubmit a Request with updated jwt token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I have an end point which issues a JWT token:

`/getJwt`

```js
token: {
  "access_token": "kjhfdhglkfhjkjfhgkjfghdkjhgkjdsgfkjhdfkjgkjhfujksfknbvckjfhdbncvujkdhgvbnfjkdghnbv",
  "expires_in": 2592000, // this is equal to 30 days  - I dont have information when it is generated
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

And my application has various end points to get data like:

```js
/getUser  
/getbusinesses
```

and so on ...

All this end points need JWT to access. 
If the JWT expires, I get following response back:

```js
{
  "code": "401",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "errorList": [{
    "code": "AUTH0007",
    "message": "Malformed JWT token",
    "fieldName": "Authorization"
  }]
}
```

`code:"AUTH0007"` is unique for JWT expiry.

Can I make a request to `getJwt` only based on the error response I get back from above end points and resubmit the failed request or do I need to ask user to trigger the request again?
I'm open to suggestion to implement any better approach.

I am successfull in making call to JWT for every req - I want to make a call only when it fails.

simple 'GET Request'

```js
axios.get('/user')
  .then((result) => {
    res.status(200).json(result.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response.status === 401 && err.response.data.errorList.code === "AUTH0007") {
      //utill function to get jwt token and update the token in code
      // at this point can I send request back with updated token or do I need to ask user to trigger the new req
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach to handle this would be to redirect users to login page (when you get a **401**) where they can re-authenticate. So you can fetch a fresh JWT and allow user to trigger the API call again.

Comment: yeah right know I am sure I can do that.

is it not possible to resubmit the request based on error?
(we update the token ourselves - no need of any user info for updating jwt token)
my app architecture UI - API1 - API2
Request from API1 need jwt to make request to API2
On API1 can I update the jwt after expiring and resubmit UI request

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you don't want user to sign in again after the JWT expires.

Comment: After you get a 401 push the request url and payload into an array and retry those failed requests after you fetch a fresh JWT.

Comment: will try that sghosh. Thanks